# PowerBI: What to use in place of SELECTEDVALUE for SAC hierarchies

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery, m

I am struggling in finding the solution for a visual. The visual is a matrix.
we are trying to recreate SAC Hierarchies in Power BI.
I have one fact and one dimension table.
The dimension table has the hierarchies this is what made me confused.

Dimension Table:

| rep_item_dim_id | rep_item_id | parent_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ALL_MEASURES | root |
| 2 | KF.999 | root |
| 3 | KF.001 | ALL_MEASURES |
| 4 | KF.002 | ALL_MEASURES |
| 5 | KF.003 | ALL_MEASURES |
| 6 | KF.003.01 | KF.003 |
| 7 | KF.003.02 | KF.003 |
| 8 | KF.002.01 | KF.002 |
| 9 | KF.002.02 | KF.002 |
| 10 | KF.004 | ALL_MEASURES |
| 11 | KF.005 | ALL_MEASURES |
| 12 | KF.006 | root |

Fact Table :

| currency | rep_item_dim_id |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 9 |
| 67 | 9 |
| 34 | 8 |
| 45 | 8 |
| 68 | 8 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 59 | 4 |
| 80 | 3 |
| 99 | 3 |

The fact table doesn't have data for all the rep_item_ids, whereas, below are the measures that I have to create in Power BI

KF.003 = KF.003.01 + KF.003.02

KF.004=KF003/KF002 i.e., (sum of currencies of rep_item_id=5)/(sum of currencies of rep_item_id =4)

KF.005=KF001*KF002 i.e., (sum of currencies of rep_item_id=3) multiplied with (sum of currencies of rep_item_id =4)

KF006= if KF003>0 then 1-(KF003/KF001) else 0.i.e., if sum of currencies of rep_item_id=5 is greater than 0, then (1 - (sum of currencies of rep_item_id=5)/(sum of currencies of rep_item_id =3) else 0.

I did create these measures. and for my matix visual, the first hierarchy is parent_rep_item_id and next comes the rep_item_id.

I get that I can use SELECTEDVALUE and display the measure if they are in the same hierarchy.

What to do when the hierarchies are different. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten this hierarchy out.  See [Parent-child hierarchies - DAX Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/).  eg

[image]

becomes

[image]